# How to completely symmetrize and antisymmetrize $T^{i\{jk\}}$

Tags: tensors

I originally asked [a similar question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/720590/192918) in the physics section, but now I realize that it is more appropriate to ask it here. I actually another post which directly gives that specific answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/637124/192918), but I want to understand how I can manage this algebra.

I need to symmetrize a not fully symmetrized tensor (e.g. $T^{i\{jk\}}$). There are some related answers that I found such as [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2223008/567636), but again it does not say anything if two of the indices of the rank 3 tensor is already symmetrized.

Comment: Do you know how to symmetrise $T^{ijk}$?

Comment: I don't know the whole theory, but when I see for example [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/353986/symmetry-in-terms-of-matrices/355477#355477) I can understand what a symmetric tensor look like. On the other hand, since I don't know about the symmetric group yet, I can't understand this: $$
(T_S)_{i_1,\dots,i_p} = \frac{1}{p!} \sum_{\sigma \in \mathfrak{S}_p} T_{i_{\sigma(1)} , \dots i_{\sigma(p)}} \, ,
$$

Comment: If $\sigma$ is an element of the symmetric group on $p$ elements, then $\sigma(1), \dots, \sigma(p)$ is just a permutation of $1, \dots, p$. So for example, $(T_S)_{i_1,i_2} = \frac{1}{2}(T_{i_1,i_2} + T_{i_2,i_1})$. Do you think you can write out the formula for the $(T_S)^{ijk}$?

Comment: Yes, in that case it should be: $(T_S)^{ijk} = \frac{1}{3!}(T^{ijk}+T^{ikj}+T^{jik}+T^{jki}+T^{kij}+T^{kji})$

Comment: Correct, and because $T$ is already symmetric in the last two indices, some of those terms are equal, e.g. $T^{ijk} = T^{ikj}$.

Comment: So, in his case it becomes $(T_S)^{ijk} = \frac{1}{3}(T^{ijk} + T^{jik} + T^{kij})$. Thank you :))

Comment: Yes. Something similar happens for antisymmetrisation.